# Why didn't Windows update the display driver automatically?

Tags: windows-10, amd-radeon, intel-graphics

New Lenovo E460 running Windows 10 Pro v1511 for a few weeks. Attempted upgrade to anniversary edition v1607 but after update it was in 640x480 resolution because the Intel HD Graphics 520 stopped with error code 43. Attempted to update the driver in place but still didn't work so backed out to the earlier edition (nice feature).

I then went sniffing around the existing driver versions. There are two graphics chips in Lenovo E460 - the Intel HD Graphics 520 on the i7 CPU and an AMD Radeon R7 M360 which I think kicks in to drive the external HDMI monitor.

On the restored system, the Intel and AMD drivers were at 20.19.15.4312 and 15.201.1101.0 dated 2015.

I manually selected the "Update drivers" and the drivers updated to 20.19.15.4483 and 15.201.1101.0 respectively dated 2016. NOTE: one can't easily find the Intel 20.19.15.4483 driver online. The Lenovo and Intel sites list slightly earlier version. Anyway, that's an aside.

My question is why didn't Windows 10 automatically update to these versions? I thought drivers were automatically updated but maybe I'm mistaken.

I've not yet re-tried the anniversary update yet...

Comment: There could be many reasons; guaranteed way to get them; go to Intel and AMDs website

Comment: AMD and Intel have to publish drivers to Windows Update, Device Manager of the drivers had already been installed, would have found them, the publish process might even be different.

Comment: Because the Windows upgrade process Sucks, always has.

Answer (score 1):

Drivers that Microsoft or laptop manufactures provide are usually the most stable and compatible drivers.  This doesn't necessary mean the newest drivers which may have less compatibility overall for different types of hardware/software combination.  For example, the last driver my laptop maker provided is dated 2014.  However, I can download the newest, or even beta drivers, from Intel (for my HD 4000) directly from Intel's website.

Here's the link for yours: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/88355/Intel-HD-Graphics-520-for-6th-Generation-Intel-Core-Processors

You can do the same for the AMD part: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/mobile?os=Windows%2010%20-%2064

From what I've learned on mines (HD 4000 + Nvidia GeForce GT 650M), the Intel drives the internal and external displays (HDMI or VGA) by default.  The Nvidia kicks in when needed.  For example, when you run a 3D Game, the Nvidia will be used.  The Nvidia software is able to do this automatically or you can actually select it per program basis.  So I can actually force the system to use the Nvidia card for Excel if I wanted to.  I'm not sure if AMD has something like that for theirs but you can install it and try.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the dual graphics adapters. I've always wondered why there were two.